# Using UNC Share with IIS ASP.NET 4.6.1

Tags: permissions, asp.net, iis-8, unc

I have some **ASP.NET 4.6.2** web sites that I want to run from a **UNC share**. The reason why I am doing this is to implement IIS Shared Config but as a first step I just want the nodes to run properly.

Each server (the multiple web servers and the server with the UNC share) are **members of the same domain**, the **app pools** for each web server is running under a **standard domain "service" account**, and the accounts have **read/write** access to both the share and the underlying folders/files. (I initially tried running with minimal permissions but that did not work.) The apps are using WS-Federation **claims** so the sites are set to **Anonymous**.

The site **almost** works in that the MVC views and CSS stylesheets are rendered but other **static** content like **images** and **fonts** come back with **401 Unauthorized**. The odd thing (*one of the odd things*) is that the static css, images, and font files are all under the **same** /Content folder but the css works.

My thought is that even though the app pool is running under a domain account with proper permissions, the image and font static content is being accessed via a **different** account other than what is used for the app pool. This *seems* to be born out by the fact that css and javascript static content works because it is **bundled** in the web application and the images and fonts *could be* served by IIS directly?

In addition, I used **Sysinternals Process Monitor** from each web server to watch the file I/O requests. What is puzzling is that for the resources returning 401, I see **some** requests with **Success** result whereas other requests for the same resource return **Access Denied**. **Both** requests are executing **CreateFile** operations, **both** requests are listed with the **User** set to domain-based app pool account, but the **failed** request shows **Impersonating: NT AUTHORITY\IUSR** on the properties dialog.

I even tried adding each of the web server computer accounts with permissions to the share and underlying folders but that did not make a difference.

What am I missing?